# Parsing a line with sed using regular expression

Tags: sed

Using `sed` I want to parse Heroku's log-runtime-metrics like this one:

`2016-01-29T00:38:43.662697+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: source=worker.2 dyno=heroku.17664470.d3f28df1-e15f-3452-1234-5fd0e244d46f sample#memory_total=54.01MB sample#memory_rss=54.01MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=17492pages sample#memory_pgpgout=3666pages`

the desired output is:

`worker.2: 54.01MB` *(54.01MB is being memory_total)*

I could not manage although I tried several alternatives including:

`sed -E 's/.+source=(.+) .+memory_total=(.+) .+/\1: \2/g'`

What is wrong with my command? How can it be corrected?

Comment: Since `worker.2` appears twice in the input, which one should appear in the output?  You've correctly identified which of the two 54.01MB values should appear; thanks for that.  Also, if you are using `-E`, are you using a Mac for this analysis?

Comment: those will be identical at all cases. let's say, if it's worker.1, then the second one is going to be worker.1 as well. Yes, I am using a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for the old-fashioned, reliable, non-extended `sed` expressions and make sure that the patterns are not too greedy:

```
sed -e 's/.*source=\([^ ]*\) .*memory_total=\([^ ]*\) .*/\1: \2/'
```

The `-e` is *not* the opposite of `-E`, which is primarily a Mac OS X (BSD) `sed` option; the normal option for GNU `sed` is `-r` instead.  The `-e` simply means that the next argument is an expression in the script.

This produces your desired output from the given line of data:

```
worker.2: 54.01MB
```

---

> Bonus question: There are some odd lines within the stream, I can usually filter them out using a grep pipe like `| grep memory_total`. However if I try to use it along with the `sed` command, it does not work. No output is produced with this:
>
> ```
>  heroku logs -t -s heroku | grep memory_total | sed.......
> ```

Sometimes `grep | sed` is necessary, but it is often redundant (unless you are using a `grep` feature that isn't readily supported by `sed`, such as Perl regular expressions).

You should be able to use:

```
sed -n -e '/memory_total=/ s/.*source=\([^ ]*\) .*memory_total=\([^ ]*\) .*/\1: \2/p'
```

The `-n` means "don't print by default".  The `/memory_total=/` matches the lines you're after; the `s///` content is the same as before.  I removed the `g` suffix that was there previously; the regex would never match multiple times anyway.  I added the `p` to print the line when the substitution occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the info. 
Bonus question: There are some odd lines within the stream, I can usually filter them out piping with grep like `| grep memory_total`. 
However if I try to use it along with the `sed` command, it does not work. No output is produced with this.
`heroku logs -t -s heroku | grep memory_total | sed.......`

Answer (score 2):

The `.+` after `source=` and `memory_total=` are both greedy, so they accept as much of the line as possible.  Use `[^ ]` to mean "anything except a space" so that it knows where to stop.

```
sed -E 's/.+source=([^ ]+) .+memory_total=([^ ]+) .+/\1: \2/g'
```

Putting your content into https://regex101.com/ makes it really obvious what's going on.